# Distribute Props to Each Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm getting this JSON response from API in React Native.

```
[
    {
        "cloth_image": "https://ox0%3es",
        "id": 7,
        "big_cloth_type": "t"
    },
    {
        "cloth_image": "https://qM%3D&",
        "id": 8,
        "big_cloth_type": "t"
    },
    {
        "cloth_image": "https://qM%",
        "id": 9,
        "big_cloth_type": "o"
    },
    {
        "cloth_image": "https://qD&",
        "id": 10,
        "big_cloth_type": "s"
    }
]
```

This response above is stored as this.props.clothesList from Redux.

What I want to do is, if the objects of `big_cloth_type` in the array is `t`, I want to assign them to corresponding Screen. (In this case, it's TopScreen)

From code, (This is render() function)

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Tabs initialPage={0}>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>Tops</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <TopScreen clothes={blahblah}/> <----- here I want to pass objects with 't' type to this Screen.
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>Outers</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <OutwearScreen clothes={blahblah} /> <--- here the objects with 'o'
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>Bottoms</Text></TabHeading>}>
           <BottomScreen />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>Shoes</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <ShoeScreen />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>ETC</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <EtcScreen />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
        <FABs
          active={this.state.active}
        />
      </View>
```

I can't come up with any solution so far. :(

For the suggestion of the comment, I'm posting my reducer

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CLOTHES_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state,  clothesList: action.payload }
    case CLOTHES_LIST_FAIL:
      return { ...state, }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: if u are using redux, wont it be simpler to filter it in the containers  and pass it as a new prop to the components?

Comment: @luciferous That sounds great! I just posted my reducer. Is the performance better if I assign `top, bottoms, outwear, etc` props instead of one props? What can be the benefit of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a container/component approach with redux, it would be better to act on the API response in the container and pass it as props to the component

For eg:

```
let getTrousers = (data) =>{
   return data.filter( (item) => { item. big_cloth_type === 't') } )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state,ownprops) => {
   let apiresponse = state.clothesList;
   let trousers = getTrousers(apiresponse); 
   /*do similarly for different cloth types*/

  return { 
   trousers,
   shoes,
   outerwear,
   tops

   }

}
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ClothesComponent)

Now in your ClothesComponent , as you had described earlier you can

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Tabs initialPage={0}>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>Tops</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <TopScreen clothes={this.props.tops}/> <----- here I want to pass objects with 't' type to this Screen.
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>Outers</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <OutwearScreen clothes={this.props.outerwear} /> <--- here the objects with 'o'
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>Bottoms</Text></TabHeading>}>
           <BottomScreen />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>Shoes</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <ShoeScreen />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={<TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabHeadingStyle}>ETC</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <EtcScreen />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
        <FABs
          active={this.state.active}
        />
      </View>
```

Doing your data manipulation in the container ,instead of the component has it advantages . Primarily it keeps your component 'dumb' i.e it performs only rendering with the given data and not anything else.

I'd recommend reading [React with Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) and  [smart vs dumb components by Dan](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) . This should clear a lot of things up !

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you can do is to filter the array either on the reducer if you want to store it or before render like

```
const filteredList = this.props.clothesList.filter((item) => item.big_cloth_type === "t"))
```

You can use this list to show the filtered as you wanted

UPDATE:
An example here which is using filter on render function. What is critical to notice here is applying the **key parameter** on the component which is the parent of each item. **React is using the key parameter to decide from the shadow DOM if it needs to change the item.**

You can find more info about it on the original facebook react page [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
render() {

    const filteredList = this.props.clothesList.filter((item) => item.big_cloth_type === "t"))

    return (
        <View>
            {filteredList.map((item) => (
                <Text key={item.id}>item.name</Text>
            ))}
        </View>
    );

}
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know we can call `filter` from objects. Thanks! Um should I filter 5 times?

Comment: i recon do it from reducer if you need it so many times so when you fetch new items it will automatically filtered and stored in lists

Comment: Thanks! I just posted my reducer on my question. But I heard it is bad if we have too many props. Is it ok to assign top, bottoms, outwear, etc props instead of one prop (clothesList)?

Comment: i got now what you mean, you have different clothes, fabrics etc. So run it on the render() and for each item put the key={id}. Filter is really fast if there is no change on filter react will not render but all of this will depend on the key

Comment: Could you explain it on the answer?

Comment: of course you can see my answer above. let me know if this makes sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155336/discussion-between-panagiotis-vrs-and-john-baek).